# Socket.io how to get room id

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, socket.io, server-side

I have problem, i want to get **ONLY** room id

I know about `io.sockets.manager.rooms` but it returns object :/

In code (i send a list of rooms to client and he checks id)

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

   socket.join('main');
   socket.emit('start',io.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id]);      

});
```

and client:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3250');                           
         socket.on('start', function(data) {    
            panel.innerHTML = data;
                }
```

**THE SOLUTION IS:**

```
 var keys = function( object ) {
  if ( !(object && typeof object === 'object') ) {
    return null;
  }
  var result = [];
  for (var key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      result.push(key)
    }
  }
  return result;
}

   var obiekt = io.sockets.manager.rooms;

   socket.emit('rooms', keys(obiekt))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you need here. Do you want to return an array of room names? If so, you can just get the keys from the object returned by io.sockets.manager.rooms, e.g. using a helper function provided by Underscore:

```
socket.emit('rooms', _.keys(io.sockets.manager.rooms) );
```

EDIT: I've used Underscore here, but you can also code your own keys function, by looping through the objects properties, with something like this:

```
var keys = function( object ) {
  if ( !(object && typeof object === 'object') ) {
    return null;
  }
  var result = [];
  for (var key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      result.push(key)
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Note that this might miss some edge cases, but you get the idea

Comment: Yes Yes I mean it! but i have problem with your code, i get error: `ReferenceError: _ is not defined`

Comment: I took [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) as an example helper library to get the "keys" function, you'll have to add that library to your project in order to use it.

Comment: I change little function and i have:

Comment: `var object = io.sockets.manager.rooms;    
   socket.emit('start', function( object ){
    if ( !(object && typeof object === 'object') ) {
    return null;
  }
  var result = [];
  for (var key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      result.push(key)
    }
  }
  return result;
   })`

Comment: It return: function ack() { self.packet({ type: 'ack' , args: io.util.toArray(arguments) , ackId: packet.id }); }

Comment: If you do that you're emitting a function (and thus an acknowledgment, in socket.io's terms). You need to define the function first, then call `socket.emit('rooms', keys(object))`.